# Given an array find median of subarray form index l:r where l<r

Tags: algorithm

How to find median of subarray from indel l:r where there are many queries to find median in unsorted array of length n

Comment: https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/22492/sorting-editorial

Comment: 1. sort array (n log n time), 2. lookup middle value (constant time)

Comment: here i need to make m (m>n) queries with different l and r values in array to find median in those m sub array.